# remove KDE notifications on "Language support is incomplete"

Tags: ubuntu, notifications, locale, kde-plasma

I'm continuously getting notification 
"Language support is incomplete, additional packages are required." in KDE system tray, with only option to obey it and install a hundred of packages. It is happening from a long time ago, I have seen this notification since KDE4.

I guess this is due ru_RU locale for Number/Time/Date formats.

Could you give an advise how can I configure this?

I want to believe there should be a better solution then just removing
 *software-properties-kde qapt-batch kubuntu-notification-helper muon*

Answer (score 3):

I had my language set and still had the issue in Kubuntu.

[Image of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgfhU.png)Go to System Settings > Personalization > Other Notifications and uncheck Incomplete language Support

Answer (score 2):

I installed full language on my systems using this command (replace `en` by your code language):

`sudo apt install $(check-language-support -l en)`

Answer (score 0):

Please go to:

`Settings` -> `System settings` -> `Personalization` -> `Regional settings`.

Select your language. If unset, KDE assumes you need every language file it has.

Comment: This doesn't turn off the notifications. I had a language set and still got them. Jade's answer is correct.